# Azure Pipeline, Mac runner and dotnet dev-cert task hang

Tags: azure-devops, .net-7.0, abp, maui-blazor

First some context :

- Azure Pipeline configured to use macos as VM Image
- Trying to have a PR Pipeline for an ABO.io project (blazor maui, both web and mobile app for android, ios)
- Trying to use macos based agent so we can build both ios and android version in the same PR pipeline.
- Using .Net 7.0

By default with ABP.io, you need to generate a certificate that is used for signing. So I basically have a step in my pipeline that is the following:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Generate authserver.pfx'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\src\projectname.HttpApi.Host
      dotnet dev-certs https -v -ep authserver.pfx -p $(passPhrase)
```

This works perfectly when running the pipeline on a Windows-based agent, but when I switch to a macos based runner, it partially works but hang forever on this before timing out :

```
[23] Saving certificate 'redacted - CN=localhost - Valid from 2023-10-25 17:28:04Z to 2024-10-25 17:28:04Z - IsHttpsDevelopmentCertificate: true - IsExportable: true' to authserver.pfx with private key.
```

What am I missing here? I've been struggling with that for hours without finding any solutions. Thanks a lot for anybody who can shed some light on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that we cannot generate/export the development certificate with the command `dotnet dev-certs https` on MacOS machine, unless we remove the one that is already installed on the machine. (Haven't tested on my Mac yet).

However, I used the `clean` option first to clean HTTPS development certificates from the MacOS agent machine and then generate the development certificate; it worked.

Here are my steps for your refence.

```
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: PowerShell Script
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: dotnet dev-certs https --clean -v
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: PowerShell Script
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        dotnet dev-certs https -ep authserver.pfx -p $(passPhrase) -v
      workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/AbpIoAzureDevops.HttpApi.Host
```

[image]

See more details in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-dev-certs). Hope the information may help resolve your issue.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Kind of funny though that Windows doesn't care if the cert is already present but Mac does. I also think it needs to be done in two steps like you did because I tried it in the same task, running both commands, and it wouldn't work, that is odd. Buy anyway, that was it, thanks a lot!

Comment: So just to keep up-to-date, I've been able to combine both commands in the same PS task. Don't ask me why it wasn't working previously 

Comment: Hahaha, good to know and cheers!